# Splitting of row according to term condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ID  term
1   12-60
2   36-48
3   12-96
```

Expectation:-Whenever there is range apart from 12-96 ,rows should be split into multiple of 12.So result should come like

```
1 12
1 24
1 36
1 48
1 60
2 36
2 48
3 null
```

Comment: If you splitted the column `term` in to two separate ones, `term_start` and `term_end` the solution would be simpler.

Comment: Lets assume that I have split term into two columns then how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can use a recursive CTE for this.  It is a little complicated because you want to do this for all but one term.  But:

```
with tt as (
      select id, term, try_convert(int, left(term, charindex('-', term) - 1)) as term_start,
             try_convert(int, stuff(term, 1, charindex('-', term), '')) as term_end
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, term_start, term_end
      from tt
      where term <> '12-96'
      union all
      select id, term_start + 12, term_end
      from cte
      where term_start < term_end
     )
select id, term_start
from cte
union all
select id, null
from t
where term = '12-96'
order by id, term_start;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbc64f4064d250cab1d794d0c04b5d0a) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are split into `term_start` and `term_end` you can use a recursive CTE. For example:

```
with
n as (
  select id, term_start, term_end
  from t 
  where term_start <> 12 or term_end <> 96
 union all
  select id, term_start + 12, term_end
  from n
  where term_start + 12 <= term_end  
)
select id, term_start from n
union all select id, null from t where term_start = 12 and term_end = 96
order by id, term_start
```

Result:

```
 id  term_start 
 --- ---------- 
 1   12         
 1   24         
 1   36         
 1   48         
 1   60         
 2   36         
 2   48         
 3   null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd9184c6c392d96e19210f68202040be).